# Checkbox unchecking issue with IE10 + IE11

Tags: php, internet-explorer, checkbox

I have a big problem with IE 10 and checkboxes. 
I use some checkboxes like this:

```
<form method="post" action="">
    <input id="trainingseinheit1" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="1" name="trainingseinheit1"> 1
    <br>
    <input id="trainingseinheit2" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="2" name="trainingseinheit2"> 2
    <br>
    <input id="trainingseinheit3" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="3" name="trainingseinheit3"> 3
    <br>
    <input id="trainingseinheit4" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="4" name="trainingseinheit4"> 4
    <br>
    <input id="trainingseinheit5" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="5" name="trainingseinheit5"> 5
    <br>
    <input id="trainingseinheit6" type="checkbox" checked="checked" value="6" name="trainingseinheit6"> 6
    <input type="hidden" name="teanzahl" value="6" />
</form>
```

And after sending I will check with php which checkbox is checked and do something:

```
$zahl = 1;

while($zahl <= $_POST['teanzahl'])
{
    $tezahl = "trainingseinheit".$zahl;

    if(isset($_POST[$tezahl]))
    {
        // do something ...
    }

    $zahl++;  
}
```

In Firefox, Chrome etc it works fine. The PHP code realize which elements are checked and which not. But in IE10 and IE11 it thinks that all elements are checked (even if I uncheck all). 
Another strange thing is, when I echo the value of the checkbox field like this:

```
echo $tezahl." = ".$_POST[$tezahl]." ... ";
```

In Firefox it looks like this:

```
trainingseinheit1 = 1 ... 
trainingseinheit2 = 2 ... 
trainingseinheit3 = 3 ... 
trainingseinheit4 = 4 ... 
...
```

But in IE10 it looks like this:

```
trainingseinheit1 = 1 ... 
trainingseinheit2 = 1 ... 
trainingseinheit3 = 1 ... 
trainingseinheit4 = 1 ... 
...
```

So in IE it is always the value "1". Why that?

I don't know what I have to change for IE. Do you have a idea?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_POST);` a the start of the receiving script to see what data you actually receive.

Comment: Your code is a bit complicated and I cannot quite follow it. Could you please do an `echo '<pre>'.print_r($_POST, true).'</pre>';` at the very beginning of your script to see your `POST` values? You can also try changing `checked="checked"` into simply `checked`. Are you using jQuery to set the checked value at all? Are you using `.attr()` or `.prop()`?

Comment: I just found the solution. I have two forms and the one submit sendet both in IE. Now I changed the name and the position of the form elements. Now it works. Hard to describe ... but solved.

Answer (score 0):

1) Try to change checkbox values, for example, 'a1', 'a2' and etc.

2) Try to change name of checkboxes to `trainingseinheit[]` (don't forget to change php)